# Shortcut to launch Spyder does not work

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, spyder

I want to create a keyboard shortcut to launch Spyder. I used as command `spyder` and I tried different keyboard shortcuts (Super+Y, Super+P, Super+S), and for some reason none of them manages to launch Spyder. If I type `spyder` in the terminal the app opens without any problem, but if I press the keys of the shortcut simply nothing happens. The shortcuts are not already taken by other commands. I have no problem with other custom shortcuts. I have Ubuntu 20.04 on an Acer Extensa 15.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Terminal and type

`which spyder`

You get something like

`/usr/bin/spyder`

Paste this into the shortcut command.